# ChromeCast Notification not visible when app sent to background

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I want to show chromecast notification and lock screen from my app. Currently i'm using CastCampaignLibrary-android. As per the sample app initialized `CastConfiguration` and `VideoCastManager` in Application class.

```
String applicationId = getString(R.string.app_id);
CastConfiguration options = new CastConfiguration.Builder(applicationId)
            .enableAutoReconnect()
            .enableDebug()
            .enableLockScreen()
            .enableNotification()
            .enableWifiReconnection()
            .setCastControllerImmersive(true)
            .setLaunchOptions(false, Locale.getDefault())
            .addNamespace(NAMESPACE)
            .setNextPrevVisibilityPolicy(CastConfiguration.NEXT_PREV_VISIBILITY_POLICY_DISABLED)
            .addNotificationAction(CastConfiguration.NOTIFICATION_ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE, true)
            .addNotificationAction(CastConfiguration.NOTIFICATION_ACTION_DISCONNECT, true)
            .build();

VideoCastManager.initialize(this, options);
```

added the following lines in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.remotecontrol.VideoIntentReceiver" />

    <service android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService" />

    <service android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.reconnection.ReconnectionService" />
```

when the application sent to background the remotecontrol notification not shown. Don't know whats wrong with my code. Help me to fix this.

**MediaInfo Initialized as follow**

```
MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);

    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, mEpisode.getmName());
    movieMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(mEpisode.getmBannerImageUrl())));
    movieMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(mEpisode.getmBannerSmallImageUrl())));

    try {
        MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(mEpisode.getmName() + ":" + mEpisode.getId())
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setContentType("video/mp4")
                .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
                .setCustomData(new JSONObject(customMessage))
                .build();

        mVideoManager.loadMedia(mediaInfo, false, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Note:** I'm using CustomReceiver for casting.

Comment: First, change the xml description of the notification service in the manifest to the one that is mentioned in the CCL's documentation, or look it up from the CastVideos-android-v2. Second, if you run the sample app (CastVideos-android-v2), will things work fine?

Comment: @AliNaddaf Manifest xml changed now(See the edit in question). 
Sample app working fine in the same device which i used for my app.

Comment: Is it possible that you may have disabled notifications for your app (in Android)? If you are using CCL from source (rather than the aar), then you should be able to debug the issue on your side to see what is happening.

Comment: @AliNaddaf from log, I found that getRemoteMediaInformation() is always null. I'm using custom receiver, so initialized the MediaInfo(as mentioned in question) in my main activity.